# memset() was called for array[]. But another array gets emptied in C

Tags: arrays, c

I don't understand this thing. about memset in C

1. I stored **`john`** in `array[]`.
2. Then I created `char* megaArray[10]` which can store 10 strings.
3. I assigned `megaArray[0] = array`. So **`john`** gets stored in 0 position of `megaArray[]`.
4. I called `memset()` to reset **`array[]`**. array gets emptied.
5. **Why does  `tokens[0]` gets emptied if I called `memset()` for `array[]` ?**

Please Help,

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char array[] = "john";
    printf("%s is the name\n",array);
    
    char* megaArray[10];
    megaArray[0] = array;
    
    printf("%s is the name in mega Array\n",megaArray[0]);
    
    memset(array, '\0', sizeof(array));
    
    printf("%s is the name after memset\n",array);
    
    printf("'%s' is the name in mega Array after memset\n",megaArray[0]);
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you think, is the difference between `array` and `megaArray[0]`?

Comment: "So john gets stored" No, `john` is not moved or copied anywhere in that instruction.

Comment: Where is `tokens[0]`?

Comment: I assume `tokens` is a typo and should be `megaArray`, correct?

Comment: You are copying a *pointer*. Remember that an array appearing in most expressions (with some exceptions) gets converted to a pointer to its first element.

Comment: There is one array containing `"john"`. If you change that, then anything that points there also reports the change.

Comment: See [Common string handling pitfalls in C programming](https://software.codidact.com/posts/284849) for a beginner FAQ.

Answer (score 2):

The assignment

```
megaArray[0] = array;
```

doesn't create a copy of `array`.

Instead it makes `megaArray[0]` point to (the first element of) `array`. It's equivalent to:

```
megaArray[0] = &array[0];
```

Somewhat graphically it looks like this (after the assignment):

```
+--------------+     +----------+----------+-----+----------+
| megaArray[0] | --> | array[0] | array[1] | ... | array[4] |
+--------------+     +----------+----------+-----+----------+
| megaArray[1] | --> ?
+--------------+
| ...          |
+--------------+
| megaArray[9] | --> ?
+--------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char* megaArray[10];
```

is an array of char-pointers. So when you assign

```
megaArray[0] = array;
```

You let the first array element "point" to the string stored in the variable `array`. It does not copy the string. `megaArray[0]` now contains an address to `array` and its literaly the same string at the same memory location. So memsetting `array` changes one and the same string.

Answer (score 0):

`char* megaArray[10];` is simple array of pointers.

`megaArray[0] = array;` it assigns the pointer `megaArray[0]` with reference (address) of `array`. It does not allocate new memory or copy the data.

```
printf("'%s' is the name in mega Array after memset\n",megaArray[0]);
```

prints the `array` which was zeroed by `memset` as `megaArray[0]` contains a pointer to `array`

If you want to make the copy of the string held in `array`

```
megaArray[0] = strdup(array);
```

or

```
megaArray[0] = malloc(sizeof(array));
memcpy(megaArray[0], array, sizeof(array));
```

Comment: You've cleared my doubt. Thanks.